# m2e seems to refresh entire workspace on every eclipse build

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

Whenever I try to build my eclipse workspace, the progress bar stops at 20% for about 15 seconds. I see eclipse refreshing every single resource in the project and if I expand the details pane it seems to be invoking the "Maven Project Builder".

I tried unchecking the maven project builder in the project preferences and the build then completes in less than a second, but I need the maven build to run as there are some post compile steps that need to run. I checked the log file and nothing seems to jump out, there are a couple lines that indicate resources are being copies, i think from the src area to the test area. Should I try to disable this copy in the lifecyle mapping?